# Javascript Referencing variables out of scope

Tags: javascript

Here is an overly simplified example of what I want to do. Currently I have something like this:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    var obj ={
        render:[arg1]
    };
    obj.render.forEach(function(theArg) {
        console.log(theArg)
    });
}
foo('one','two');
//Displays 'one'
```

I want to be able to modify 'obj' externally and add 'arg2' (or other variables that are scoped inside function foo) to the obj.render array. So something like this:

```
var obj ={
    render:[arg1]
};
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    obj.render.forEach(function(theArg) {
        console.log(theArg)
    });
}
function setup() {
    obj.render.push(arg2);
}
setup();
foo('one','two');
//Need to display 'one' and 'two' in console
```

The setup function represents additional scripts that may or may not be present and they need to modify the object 'obj'. Unfortunately arg1 and arg2 are out of scope in this instance so this code will not run. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Add a 3rd argument taking the `obj` to the function? It would be like `function foo(arg1, arg2, obj)`, and just pass `obj` as the 3rd... By the way your question is quite unclear, maybe giving a bit more context, like showing how the function is called could give you better and more appropriate answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I want to be able to modify 'obj' externally*"? In the example code you've shown there is no reason why you wouldn't put the declaration inside the `foo` function just like in your first snippet. Please add the other code that you want to use with `obj`, and show us how/where you are calling `foo`.

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Or show the part of the code with the actual function calls?

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/wpugkdx7/

Comment: I have updated the code examples.

Answer (score 0):

change your function signature to include `obj`

`function foo(arg1, arg2)`

to

`function foo(obj)`

then within your function loop through the `render` property like you are already.

`obj.render.forEach(function(theArg)`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable `obj` globally.

Then, have your function have `obj` a passed argument as well.

Do what you need to do with said `obj` inside function.